# .htaccess redirect with Multiple query parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to use following URL for my web site.

```
http://mywebsite.com/product.php
to
http://mywebsite.com/product

http://mywebsite.com/product.php?id=5
to
http://mywebsite.com/product/5


http://mywebsite.com/product.php?action=delete&id=5
to
http://mywebsite.com/product/delete/5



http://mywebsite.com/product.php?action=edit&id=3
to
http://mywebsite.com/product/edit/3
```

I use this code on my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^product product.php

RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ product.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ product.php?id=$1
```

But problem is when i use http://mywebsite.com/product/5 and display with GET variable,
it does not pass the id parameter and how can i achieve the multiple query from my url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^product/?$ product.php [L]

RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/delete/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ product.php?action=delete&id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^product/edit/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ product.php?action=edit&id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the difference between two lines? RewriteRule ^product/?$ product.php [L]               and                 RewriteRule ^product product.php

Comment: Ashis , **^product** matches a **product.php** or productss any character after **t** because there is no end of line. using **$** restricts it to match **product** and a optional slash only. **$** is important here to prevent rewrite loop error.

Comment: Now got it. Thanks for clarification

Comment: [L] is a rewrite flag of apache mod_rewrite, it means Last (it tells apache to stop processing other rules if the request  has matched the currunt rule)